# Не переносятся зоны Master > slave

Tags: dns, bind

Поднял slave сервер, использую rndc. Сервер находится за NAT.
При попытке перенести зону выдает следующую ошибку:

```
06-Jan-2017 13:00:59.593 general: info: zone domain.com/IN: Transfer started.
06-Jan-2017 13:00:59.594 xfer-in: info: transfer of 'domain.com/IN' from <master DNS IP>#53: connected using 10.0.2.4#42991
06-Jan-2017 13:00:59.896 xfer-in: error: transfer of 'domain.com/IN' from <master DNS IP>#53: failed while receiving responses: NXDOMAIN
06-Jan-2017 13:00:59.896 xfer-in: info: transfer of 'domain.com/IN' from <master DNS IP>#53: Transfer completed: 0 messages, 0 records, 0 bytes, 0.302 secs (0 bytes/sec)
```

При этом все порты открыты (как TCP, так и UDP, 953 и 53). Master сервер исправно работает.
lsof на slave

```
root@admindns:/var/log/bind# lsof -Pni :53
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
named   20620 bind   20u  IPv4 392123      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:53 (LISTEN)
named   20620 bind   21u  IPv4 392125      0t0  TCP 10.0.2.4:53 (LISTEN)
named   20620 bind  512u  IPv4 392122      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:53
named   20620 bind  513u  IPv4 392124      0t0  UDP 10.0.2.4:53
root@admindns:/var/log/bind# lsof -Pni :953
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
named   20620 bind   22u  IPv4 392128      0t0  TCP *:953 (LISTEN)
root@admindns:/var/log/bind#
```

lsof на master

```
[root@panel ~]# lsof -Pni :953
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
named   29304 named   21u  IPv4 445846      0t0  TCP *:953 (LISTEN)
[root@panel ~]# lsof -Pni :53
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
dnsmasq  1112 nobody    4u  IPv4  27041      0t0  UDP *:53
dnsmasq  1112 nobody    5u  IPv4  27042      0t0  TCP *:53 (LISTEN)
dnsmasq  1112 nobody    6u  IPv6  27043      0t0  UDP *:53
dnsmasq  1112 nobody    7u  IPv6  27044      0t0  TCP *:53 (LISTEN)
named   29304  named  512u  IPv6 445837      0t0  UDP *:53
named   29304  named  513u  IPv6 445837      0t0  UDP *:53
named   29304  named  514u  IPv4 445840      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:53
named   29304  named  515u  IPv4 445840      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:53
named   29304  named  516u  IPv4 445842      0t0  UDP 10.0.0.4:53
named   29304  named  517u  IPv4 445842      0t0  UDP 10.0.0.4:53
named   29304  named  518u  IPv4 445844      0t0  UDP 172.17.0.1:53
named   29304  named  519u  IPv4 445844      0t0  UDP 172.17.0.1:53
[root@panel ~]#
```

Comment: NXDOMAIN - это домен не найден. вы уверены что на мастере зона точно поднята ? что говорит на мастере `dig SOA domain.com @127.0.0.1`. Так же проверьте dig с другой машины, указав после собаки ip мастера

Comment: Вот 
http://pastebin.com/yLmmTxam

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в dnsmasq, надо было его просто выключить.